# Hide an element using a specific id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html structure:

```
 <div id="main">
    <div id="box" data-id="1">
    <div id="box" data-id="2">
    <div id="box" data-id="3">
    <div id="box" data-id="4">
 </div>
```

When I've a click event in jquery on a button I want that the box with data-id="1" become hidden:

```
$('#box[data-id=1]').hide();
```

this is work.

However if I want that the data-id="2" become hidden:

```
$('#box[data-id=2]').hide();
```

this doesn't works and I should write like:

```
$('#main #box[data-id=2]').hide();
```

why should the last one work or the one before shouldn't?

Comment: You can assign an id to only one element. If you need to give multiple elements similar properties, use classes instead. Ids are meant to be unique in a DOM.

Comment: Because you html is invalid (duplicate `id` attributes). Your selector begins with `$('#box...` which will only ever return the first element with `id="box"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use id unique in page and you made mistake there you have define more then one box id to that div so change your html code as following :-

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="box" data-id="1">1</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="2">2</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="3">3</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="4">4</div>
</div>
```

Jquery code is same as you :-

```
$('.box[data-id=2]').hide();
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have multiple duplicate IDs on the same document context. Change it to class:

```
<div id="main">
  <div class="box" data-id="1">1</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="2">2</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="3">3</div>
  <div class="box" data-id="4">4</div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
$('.box[data-id=2]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#box[data-id='2']").hide();
```

Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rate Me If it helps</title>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#box[data-id='2']").hide();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="box" data-id="1">1</div>
        <div id="box" data-id="2">2</div>
        <div id="box" data-id="3">3</div>
        <div id="box" data-id="4">4</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use multiple elements with the same id, for such case you need to use class. i.e 
  `<div class="box" data-id="1">`
the first case ie -
 `$('#box[data-id=1]').hide();`
work because jquery can always pick the first element with that id. 
After giving classes instead of ids. Now try this `$('.box[data-id=2]').hide();` , it works.

Comment: What did this offer beyond the answers that were already here an hour before you posted it? This is just Andy's answer but with the wrong selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiples elements with the same id, these should be unique

replace "id=" by "class=" and "#box" by ".box"